Python using a for with a while loop
Currently I have this
for word in words:
   print(word)

but now i want to introduce a while loop, to only execute that as long as an image (spinner.png) is located on the screen. like this
while True:

    try:    
       location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('c:/images/spinner.png', region=(140, 240, 300, 100), confidence=0.5) 
       for word in words:
              print(word)
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
       pass

OR like this:
for word in words:

   while True:

    try:    
       location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('c:/images/spinner.png', region=(140, 240, 300, 100), confidence=0.5) 
       print(word)
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
       pass

and looking for the pythonic way also. but confused by reading many kb on break in the inner loop.
I have not tried anything as yet, just want to know the most efficient way to code this
while True:

    try:    
       location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('c:/images/spinner.png', region=(140, 240, 300, 100), confidence=0.5) 
       for word in words:
              print(word)
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
       pass


Heres two Suggestions you could try
Option 1:
while True:
    try:    
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('c:/images/spinner.png', region=(140, 240, 300, 100), confidence=0.5) 
        if location:  # Image found
            for word in possible_words:
                print(word)
            break  # Exit the loop after printing all words once
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        pass

This option prints all words only once after detecting the image ^
Option 2:
while True:
    try:    
        location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('c:/images/spinner.png', region=(140, 240, 300, 100), confidence=0.5) 
        if location:  # Image found
            for word in possible_words:
                print(word)
        else:
            break  # Exit the loop if the image is no longer found
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        pass

This option prints each word continuously as long as the image is found ^
You potentially could also try an approach of importing a time module then incorporating the following code:
  except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:


So, Option 2 is the solution I am looking for, but when I try this, it does nothing. It stops at the while True line and wait. Not sure if this is because of the locateOnScreen. Option 1 works fine but it only prints the words once, breaks and continues with the rest of the code, with the spinner.png still present.

Option 2 worked perfectly after i removed the pass on the except statement and replaced it with break. Thanks for all the responses.

all good, glad to help. i figured yapping would eventually help.

I think your first approach works best because you only need to check if the image appear on screen once and then print all elements in the possible_words list. This way you will only need to check once whereas the second option you have to check it for every element in possible_words list. Also I think it would be better to add a break in the while loop to escape the loop once the image appears on screen to avoid being stuck in an infinite loop
while True:
    try:    
       location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('c:/images/spinner.png', region=(140, 240, 300, 100), confidence=0.5) 
       for word in possible_words:
           print(word)
       break
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
       pass


I might be wrong, but I believe an infinite loop might actually be the point?

@AndrewYim It is but not after the image is detected I think. Otherwise, the loop would just print the same list of words over and over
